# How to take in multiple inputs and put it all in one list

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a python Newbie. I tried to make a calculator that takes in user input and gives the result. I want to take the inputs from all the entries in the GUI and put them in a list when the button is pressed.

This is the command that I tried to get all the inputs, I don't know if it works or not.

```
button = tk.Button(frame, text='Calculate', bg='blue', fg='white', command=lambda: testFunction(En1.get(), En2.get(), En3.get(), En4.get(), En5.get()))
```

By the way, I don't know how to write a function that takes all the inputs and puts them in a list. can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

A function like

```
def f(*args):
    return args
```

Takes in multiple arguments and receives them as a list called `args`. For example, `f(1, 2, 3)` returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

However, why not just put the entries in a list? For example:

```
entries = [En1, En2, En3, En4, En5]
entries_get = []
for entry in entries:
    entries_get.append(entry.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be defining your command with such a complex lambda. Ideally, the button should call a function that takes no parameters. That makes the code considerably more easy to debug.

```
def do_calculation():
    e1 = En1.get()
    e2 = En2.get()
    e3 = En3.get()
    e4 = En4.get()
    e5 = Ent5.get()
    the_list = [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5)
    testFunction(the_list)
...
button = tk.Button(..., command=do_calculation)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. This is my first time posting here and I just made my first program. YAY

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to replace that lambda function, try to define another function like that:
(e is your entry widget)

```
def add() :
    lst=[]
    x=e.get()
    lst.append(x)
    e.delete(0,END)
```